# Javascript - Multidimensional array object to array

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, javascript-objects

I'm new to Node.js and I want to access a particular set of information from an object that looks like this:

```
userData: [
  {
    value: false,
    id: 1,
    title: 'Hello World',
    date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:51 PM',
    status: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    value: false,
    id: 2,
    title: 'Hello People',
    date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:48 PM',
    status: 'Active'
  },
  {
    value: false,
    id: 3,
    title: 'Hello Canary',
    date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:44 PM',
    status: 'Expired'
  }
]
```

Now I want to return an array that consist of only "title"

Example: `['Hello World', 'Hello people', 'Hello Canary']`

I have tried `Object.values(obj)` and `Object.keys(yourObject).map(key => yourObject[key])` without any luck. Can anyone please help me?

Update: I'm using ES6 and would like to optimize my code for performance

Comment: Possible duplicate of [From an array of objects, extract value of a property as array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19590865/from-an-array-of-objects-extract-value-of-a-property-as-array)

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan No luck with `var result = objArray.map(a => a.foo);`

Comment: That's exactly what your accepted answer does.

Comment: Yeah. I do realize that. It wasn't working before though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let titles = userData.map(x => x.title);`

When using [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) with an array. It returns an array made up of the return value of the function you pass it, called on each element of the array. So the above example, when used on your array of objects containing the `.title` property, will return a new array containing the titles of each object in the original array.

Comment: Your answer is partially right and it will require reassigning the processed output that is a reason I gave the downvote to you.

Comment: I tired using `return userData.map(x => x.title)` in a function. Here's the error for the same: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'header' of undefined`

Answer (score 2):

> Here's a working snippet

```js
var userData = [{
    value: false,
    id: 1,
    title: 'Hello World',
    date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:51 PM',
    status: 'Processing'
  },
  {
    value: false,
    id: 2,
    title: 'Hello People',
    date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:48 PM',
    status: 'Active'
  },
  {
    value: false,
    id: 3,
    title: 'Hello Canary',
    date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:44 PM',
    status: 'Expired'
  }
]

// Solution to your problem
let titles = userData.map(function(obj) {
  return obj.title;
});

console.log(titles);
```

> Explanation:

1. Map will execute on each object of the User Data array
2. Map method takes in a function which returns values that we want in our final array, which is, in this case 'title'
3. So after Map is done iterating through the whole list, titles of each object in the User Data array, will be collected in titles variable

Comment: Thank you for the explanation

Comment: I got it working. I was using Camel case in property. Silly me :D

Comment: Good to hear that. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this:
var userData =  [
        {
          value: false,
          id: 1,
          title: 'Hello World',
          date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:51 PM',
          status: 'Processing'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          id: 2,
          title: 'Hello People',
          date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:48 PM',
          status: 'Active'
        },
        {
          value: false,
          id: 3,
          title: 'Hello Canary',
          date: '17 February 2018 - 06:27:44 PM',
          status: 'Expired'
        }
      ];
      var newArray=[];
userData.forEach(function(entry) {
    newArray.push(entry.title);
});
alert(newArray);
```